# HTTP request failed!

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть вот такой  php скрипт

```
<?php 
$url="http://site.ru/index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1";
$xml_code = file_get_contents($url);

if (file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sitemap.xml', $xml_code))
   {
      echo "<h1>XML sitemap successfully updated</h1>";
      $xml_code = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sitemap.xml');
      $xml_code = str_replace ("</url>", "</url><br>", $xml_code);
      echo $xml_code;
   } 
      else echo "<h1>Error!</h1>";
?>
```

При попытке его выполнить получаю

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://site.ru/index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /var/www/xxxdata/www/site.ru/genmap.php on line 3
```

Что сделано не так?

Comment: наверное ваш хостер запрещает исходящие http соединения.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Изменил 2 строку скрипта на такой вид http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],но теперь получаю  php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known. 

resolf.com выглядит вот так:

domain site.ru
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: а зачем вам такое ?  в смысле вы понимаете что вы говорите - "обратиться к самому себе по http" ?

Comment: Суть скрипта - выгрузить карту сайта из плагина в файл sitemap.xml, вот поэтому и идет обращение к самому себе.

Comment: почему-бы просто не запустить ?